# Mulval: installation setup

Tags: graphviz, dot, xsb

I am trying to install mulval on my machine following this doc:

http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~xou/argus/software/mulval/readme.html

However, I am not exactly sure how to make changes to the path of XSB, dot and Mulval. 
I get the following error when I try to run "make":

```
~/mulval$ make
 (cd src/adapter; make; make install)
 make[1]: Entering directory '/home/aditya/mulval/src/adapter'
 javac GetCVEID.java -cp :/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/lib/jaxen-1.1.1.jar:/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.8-bin.jar
 make[1]: javac: Command not found
 Makefile:9: recipe for target 'GetCVEID.class' failed
 make[1]: *** [GetCVEID.class] Error 127
 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/aditya/mulval/src/adapter'
 make[1]: Entering directory '/home/aditya/mulval/src/adapter'
javac GetCVEID.java -cp :/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/lib/jaxen-1.1.1.jar:/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.8-bin.jar
make[1]: javac: Command not found
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'GetCVEID.class' failed
make[1]: *** [GetCVEID.class] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/aditya/mulval/src/adapter'
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'adapter' failed
make: *** [adapter] Error 2
```

Any help on getting this installation completed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `MULVALROOT` env variable before `make`:

for instance: `export MULVALROOT=/home/aditya/mulval`

Comment: Just a small edit: export MULVALROOT="/home/aditya/mulval"

Answer (score 0):

this error is related to javac, not installed properly:
"make[1]: **javac**: Command not found"

you can check the version with: `javac -version`

if not installed, install again with `sudo apt install default-jdk`

if you have other issues related to lex and/or bison later, install them too:

lex: `sudo apt install flex`

bison: `sudo apt install bison`